# Insert multiple columns into a single column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas, proc-sql

I am converting a SAS code to python and got stuck here.

My input table is like:-

| St | sgmt | Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | CD | 200 |
| A | PQ | 300 |

My output should be like:-

| Col | Val |
| --- | --- |
| A | 500 |
| CD | 200 |
| PQ | 300 |

500 is the sum of values of same category

Comment: maybe you could provide your SAS code in the question for clarity, this might also help future readers coming from the SAS world

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to combine the "St" and "sgmt" columns, then [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to aggregate per name:

```
(df
 .melt('Val', value_name='Col')
 .groupby('Col', as_index=False)
 ['Val'].sum()
)
```

output:

```
  Col  Val
0   A  500
1  CD  200
2  PQ  300
```